# Rails 3.1 asset pipeline with PDFKit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, pdfkit

I am using PDFkit with rails 3.1. In the past I was able to use the render_to_string function and create a pdf from that string. I then add the stylesheets as follows. My issue is that I have no idea how to access them from within the asset pipeline. (This is how I did it in rails 3.0)

```
html_string = render_to_string(:template => "/faxes/show.html.erb", :layout => 'trade_request')
kit = PDFKit.new(html_string, :page_size => 'Letter')
kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/stylesheets/trade_request.css"
```

So my question in how do i get direct access from my controller to my css file through the asset pipline?

I know I can use the Rack Middleware with PDFkit to render the pdf to the browser, but in this case i need to send the pdf off to a third party fax service.

Thanks for your help.

Ryan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one reference compiled assets from the controller in Rails 3.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409948/how-does-one-reference-compiled-assets-from-the-controller-in-rails-3-1)

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into this issue as well, and I got past it without using the asset pipeline, but accessing the file directly as I would have previously in /public. Don't know what the possible cons are to using this approach.

I guess LESS and SCSS files won't be processed as they would have if accessed through the asset pipeline.

```
      html = render_to_string(:layout => false , :action => 'documents/invoice.html.haml')
      kit = PDFKit.new(html, :encoding=>"UTF-8")
      kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root.to_s}/app/assets/stylesheets/pdf_styles.css"
      send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => "test_invoice", :type => 'application/pdf')
```

Comment: The only con I can see is you don't get to use SASS/LESS, it has to be plain CSS.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but better late than never, eh.

I'd do it like this:

```
found_asset = Rails.application.assets.find_asset( "trade_request.css" ).digest_path
kit.stylesheets << File.join( Rails.root, "public", "assets", found_asset )
```

Comment: still `Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3.1.1 stylesheets are written to /public/assets with and without the digest fingerprint.

This means that you should be able to reference these files just by changing the path in your code.

One gotcha though: if the PDF sheet is not referenced in a CSS manifest you'll have to add it to the precompile config:

`config.assets.precompile += ['trade_request.css']`

This tells sprockets to compile that file on its own.

As a (better) alternative, see if the asset_path helper works in your code. This will reference the correct file in dev and production.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am just using the application.css file so I don't believe I have to worry about the precompiling. I believe pdfkit runs a separate process, and therefor when I reference the path without the hash at the end of the file it cannot find it. IE this works:
    kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/assets/application-5c342d3a7328fd347c8ca581f6bdff60.css"

this does not:

    kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/assets/application.css"

Is there any way to get the correct file path? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up copying the css file to my public directory and referring to it in the same way i did before with rails 3. For more information check out this question: [Access stylesheet_link_tag from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825764/access-stylesheet-link-tag-from-controller)

Comment: Did you manage to improve on this solution? and to use the asset pipeline for generating the PDF?

Answer (score 0):

I landed here trying to solve this problem and none of the answers seemed to solve the issue for me. I found the accepted answer of this stack overflow post worked for me:

[How does one reference compiled assets from the controller in Rails 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409948/how-does-one-reference-compiled-assets-from-the-controller-in-rails-3-1)

I was even able to serve .css.erb files through this method.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`= stylesheet_link_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'`

Comment: Can you add more details please ? Also, as it update an old post, it would be great to explain what new solution in comparison to previous answers.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to access the stylesheet using this method:

`ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("trade_request.css")`

Making your code:

```
html_string = render_to_string(:template => "/faxes/show.html.erb", :layout => 'trade_request') 
kit = PDFKit.new(html_string, :page_size => 'Letter') 
kit.stylesheets = ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("trade_request.css")
```