# Access stylesheet_link_tag from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

Is there a was to call `stylesheet_link_tag` from the controller? I am creating a PDF file in memory and passing it along to an api call to another service. I am using PDFKit and it requires me to send the style sheet link to it. I am using Rails 3.1 and therefore need access to the asset pipeline through this method.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use this to access the stylesheet from your controller:

`ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("stylesheet_i_want.css")`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Under normal circumstances I think this would work. My issue is that I am passing this link to a pdf processor that is separate from my rails process and it requires the actual filesystem link to the file. It looks like that asset_path method provides the link to the file without the added hash of the compiled/processed css file. Ie I am able to get it to work if i pass in "#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/assets/pdf/pdf_layout-86723cb5eb9aff943867df0b379440c2.css", but this hash can change.

Comment: Try using the [digestion gem](https://github.com/spohlenz/digestion) - it will let you disable the fingerprinting on specific files/paths. Preventing the stylesheet from getting fingerprinted should let you use the `{Rails.root.to_s}` method you mentioned.

Comment: I ended up just manually placing the css file in the public folder. I looked at the gem but for now it's only a single css file that I need so I'm thinking ill just do it on my own. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This question is closely related to this one:
[How does one reference compiled assets from the controller in Rails 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409948/how-does-one-reference-compiled-assets-from-the-controller-in-rails-3-1/9780235)

See my answer there, but, more briefly, you can access the Rails asset pipeline, which is managed by the Sockets library, from `Rails.application.assets`. That will be a `Sprockets::Environment` instance, documented at the [Sprockets project](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets). You can use it like this:

```
Rails.application.assets['application.css'].pathname  #=> "/home/username/project..."
Rails.application.assets['application.css'].to_s  #=> "html, body { ..."
```