# How can I drive Rails asset pipeline from a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

In Rails, I want to drive the asset pipeline to compile and minify my js file and get the result as a string. The js file uses sprockets to combine multiple files together.

How can I do this?

This needs to be run from a controller action. It's not as simple as just serving an asset, rather, I want to get my compiled and minified JS as a string and then do something with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to access your asset.

```
view_context.asset_path 'your_file.js'
```

Check this question also

[How does one reference compiled assets from the controller in Rails 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409948/how-does-one-reference-compiled-assets-from-the-controller-in-rails-3-1)